# Javascript variable declaration and number conversion

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, conventions

I was curious in this example why the declare the variables first.
then the next line they define what the variable is. Is there a reason for this?

could you not just say

```
 var message = document.GetElementById("message").innerHTML;
```

and why do they declare Number(x) in the middle of the if statments?
If you put it before the other if statments, would it take a string and convert it to a number?

javascript:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var message, x;
    message = document.getElementById("message");
    message.innerHTML = "";
    x = document.getElementById("demo").value;
    try { 
        if(x == "")  throw "empty";
        if(isNaN(x)) throw "not a number";
        x = Number(x);
        if(x < 5)    throw "too low";
        if(x > 10)   throw "too high";
    }
    catch(err) {
        message.innerHTML = "Input is " + err;
    }
}
</script>
```

trying to understand why its written like this.

Comment: My guess is it's either: 1.) the way the author is used to writing other languages or 2.) just the way the author feels makes the code more readable.

Comment: The author is saving you from ambuguity.  He could have written `var message = ...`, but due to declaration hoisting this would produced the `var` at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By convention, variables are often declared together at the top of a function, when they can be, so that that all their names are obvious. I think JSHint and JSLint enforce this by default, for example.

The second 2 if conditionals are done after x is converted to a number, in case it was a string. If the variable was for instance the string "3" rather than the number 3, before conversion by Number(x), then 
if(x < 5) 
would be comparing a number to a string.
If it were done before all of the conditionals, it might throw an error, if it were empty, or undefined or the letter s, for example.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has a property call "hoisting", it will moving all declarations to the top of the current scope. Of course, you can use `var message = document.GetElementById("message").innerHTML;` , but actually it will become

`var message, x; 
// other variable declaration
message = document.getElementById("message");`

For second question, because you need to check if x is a actually integer first.